# Deserializing JSON with nested arrays in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm having trouble trying to deserialize this JSON here:

```
{
    "response": {
        "numfound": 1,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {
                "enID": "9999",
                "startDate": "2013-09-25",
                "bName": "XXX",
                "pName": "YYY",
                "UName": [
                    "ZZZ"
                ],
                "agent": [
                    "BobVilla"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The classes I created for this are:

```
public class ResponseRoot {
    public Response response;
}

public class Response {
    public int numfound { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public Docs[] docs;
}

public class Docs {
    public string enID { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string bName { get; set; }
    public string pName { get; set; }
    public UName[] UName;
    public Agent[] agent;
}

public class UName {
    public string uText { get; set; }
}

public class Agent {
    public string aText { get; set; }
}
```

But, whenever I call:

```
    ResponseRoot jsonResponse = sr.Deserialize<ResponseRoot>(jsonString);
```

jsonResponse ends up being null and the JSON isn't deserialized. I can't seem to tell why my classes may be wrong for this JSON.

Comment: In addition I'm getting this error:  Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'UName'

Comment: Aren't the `UName` and `agent` members on `Docs` supposed to be arrays of strings?

Comment: uname and agent look like Lists of strings in the sample json.

Comment: Have you tried  http://json2csharp.com/ ?

Comment: json2csharp.com is really g8 :) thanks @L.B

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your code suggest that the `UName` Property of `Docs` is an array of objects, but it's an array of strings in json, same goes for `agent`

try this:

```
 public class Docs
 {
   public string enID { get; set; }
   public string startDate { get; set; }
   public string bName { get; set; }
   public string pName { get; set; }
   public string[]  UName;
   public string[] agent;
 }
```

and remove the `UName` and `Agent` classes

Comment: E.g., if `UName` were really the class specified, the JSON would have `{uText: "ZZZ"}` rather than just `"ZZZ"`.

Answer (score 13):

This should work for your classes, using [`json2csharp`](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class Doc
{
    public string enID { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string bName { get; set; }
    public string pName { get; set; }
    public List<string> UName { get; set; }
    public List<string> agent { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int numfound { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public List<Doc> docs { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseRoot
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No problem, it's very handy ;)

Comment: Thank you for the link.. helped alot